# Google recaptcha v3 passe on same script, fail on another

Tags: javascript, php, grecaptcha

The same html form pass validation if form action url is same, but fail if is another.

I test that on 3 simple forms :

```
<form action="" class="reCaptCha" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="Empty" placeholder=" " required>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Empty">
    <button type="submit">{{SEARCH_RELAIS}}</button>
</form>
<form action="samepage.php" class="reCaptCha" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="Same" placeholder=" " required>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Same">
    <button type="submit">{{SEARCH_RELAIS}}</button>
</form>
<form action="anotherpage.php" class="reCaptCha" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="Another" placeholder=" " required>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Another">
    <button type="submit">{{SEARCH_RELAIS}}</button>
</form>
```

I add the token in JS. I capture the submit like that :

```
var form = $(this),
action = form.find("[name='action']").val();

grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('MYKEY', {action: action}).then(function(token) {
        form.prepend('<input type="hidden" name="tokenReCaptcha" value="' + token + '">');
        form.submit();
    });
});
```

Submit 1er and 2e form is ok, but 3e fail.
samepage.php and anotherpage.php have exactly the same test code :

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['tokenReCaptcha']))
{
    $tokenReCaptcha = $_REQUEST['tokenReCaptcha'];
    $recaptcha      = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(RECAPTCHA_SECRET);
    $resp           = $recaptcha->setExpectedAction($_REQUEST['action'])->setScoreThreshold(0.5)->verify($tokenReCaptcha, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    var_dumpt($resp,$_REQUEST['action'],$tokenReCaptcha, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);exit();
}
```

Exemple on success dump :

```
 object(ReCaptcha\Response)#2264 (7) {
    ["success":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["errorCodes":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["hostname":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
    string(18) "dev.perlesandco.fr"
    ["challengeTs":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
    string(20) "2023-05-05T08:27:53Z"
    ["apkPackageName":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["score":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
    float(0.90000000000000002)
    ["action":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
    string(5) "Empty"
  }
string(5) "Empty"
string(569) "03AL8dmw_60rSpF0jXH4CVyrSqLDCdYV290HRjk4HFNwPX5uazhAm1qhEp6v9BboYlV9mFpMfdr1vOYfZD7u0QFU0lXuPMqlDTDiEPdkaVkl10A2Kit_vfpgo24FVfB4cW9HZpa9yMMKIlLB-s2EMpUr0ydJbfyKpURrhQWM9v5bdUQArvTuavOLQbQA6KhWCiJuOTZE4t8KF5XA2IMWdIW1YmIILmPB2yolj6qn3fyt8jj7GiXVs4_Pgn6-eX7HHcfdzJVaGQ3aLkJuO1zhd4RfamRIZpr8Am0SRKtQvh7zMpZ_lHPJefvqdWTbIpqNvMZmjeBVwndaE-oLHbA0uwtUZY98VWEYy9GzqYSds9l0yyozelj-6PbuqlnksXFSunKr8plX_hQNVSKWKjz3XTEKBjf3Wu8xL0JVOlUtBmQTvY3sy0paF6LrZC8g1Gg3qRZwXW0yjqtrtQ0tI9bXXrUh55AO0hXj5mJaWuigUM8LK2ebutdWLtQ-rjfqybsEotiaYejT7kBfP1RAbR7cZstfZx150qrWVN1TuAIuzHWO5FY1QVHp-ygFQ"
```

And Fail dump :

```
object(ReCaptcha\Response)#2265 (7) {
  ["success":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["errorCodes":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "timeout-or-duplicate"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "action-mismatch"
    [2]=>
    string(23) "score-threshold-not-met"
  }
  ["hostname":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["challengeTs":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["apkPackageName":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["score":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
  NULL
  ["action":"ReCaptcha\Response":private]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(7) "Another"
string(569) "03AL8dmw-yBB-c6sdHPeVORv1_O50CXQLiLNcYjdIIqZV4ythI4APaG3R-S4AXDYpdgncKQ3yuZsrvkjNevRvzAmXJHV8dyu7Nbwd_gr7V6uJE5AMMwY4sEWZ5iOytVKaHAFbNVuPdH5thExejvSedtvm9feA_EySgbcOeNw3xGmRtgp28VPjLzcDUm3HQmSV04wbsv74b8497zs9Zpm4CCMs_ToNwNZIFLBrent98qdXUnTqZwC6R9ajlSIcUKVrqG4L2xXO3V5ZaQndSo-f4bTF_PmKHKkIClTw85dkvoZqIt_tERZbGX3p0zyHdu-5nNrn3FKTyxBP3AMNf83Mzhb7mwTF_dBjqKyuNMtCAvj85tHz9pTJ0RplxofckN0m3O2aLkJTsTmVRo9nMMJBQ55igp-kOVqG_agexG3AqfEg9TbBiSdZTFhk4PaxFJ0YlgAJa1ju3SoZlfBupmkbAUJ-3bnLtS44LI6lnH4rBJGn1_XcbRnDQ_0QlZSnmLBDn8WnYiRs-v7SNJzf84ZiBi_Tm5GenNWtAgLyR3hZpgQ7senSLCgGVtEQ"
```

I don't understand why ?

Comment: Presumably, for some reason it didn't think the page passed the captcha requirement. There doesn't appear to be anything obviously amiss with the code. Not sure if you can get any support or log info from google which describes why it didn't pass.